# Flux Disabling it for specific Windows/Monitors (VLC hardware overlay?)

Tags: video, multiple-monitors, vlc-media-player, f.lux

[F.lux](http://justgetflux.com/) is some color management application. My problem, with multiple monitors, is that I multitask. There are not distinct movie watching times, and coding/working/browser times; It is just all at once. And while it is a great application for reading text, it is less good for watching movies or god forbid drawing.

If there anyway to disable/modify F.lux on a per window, or monitor basis? Maybe just a way to disable it for video output?

I did just find this on Reddit:

> If the video is overlaid by hardware it won't be dimmed, otherwise it will.

Assuming their is not a more generic solution, how do I force VLC to use hardware overlay?

---

*Windows 7, 64*
*NVIDIA GeForce 9600 GT*

Comment: Just tried turning on VLC 64 - Input/Hardware-accelerated decoding. And it did not make any difference for the color. But for one movie it make it play in a very very jerky manner.

Comment: I am also interested in this question.

Comment: Same. They need to add this feature.